# How to give somebody a link to something that nobody else can have?

Tags: php, security, hyperlink, private

Usually when you send a link to somebody to someones social profile it will ask you to create an account to see it.  But say i didn't want to do that, rather i wanted to give them a link that could not be indexed by search engines and something that was rather complicated to guess so that the person can see the content on that link, i was thinking something like:

```
  www.domain.com/user/content/private/secured/90989834093/testcontent.php
```

How do i achieve that securely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing that, you can generate a one-off random access token and use it in a querystring. The token would be stored in a database which would know if it has been previously accessed or not. When the page is hit, the token is checked against the database, and if still active the content would be served.

As Truth has commented below, this would work well in conjunction with a Session or Cookie so you could continue to serve the authenticated user the page after the access token has been used.

Comment: Probably also usable in conjunction with Sessions and Cookies to allow the first user accessed to have access to the page (And only him).

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll add it my answer.

Comment: thanks! i was also thinking of giving the referring person to give the  option of passphrase that the person has to enter rather than having an account.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hash functions to create a string of "random" characters to create this sort of URL.

For instance , if a standart profile's page is:

```
domain.com/user/$id/show.php
```

when $id is a var which its value is the user's ID.
You can do something like this:

```
$hash = md5($id);
domain.com/user/$hash/show.php
```

The problem is that anyone can get duplicate the process and finally reach the hash.
Therefore , you should set a random string , add it to the DB (relate it to that user) and hash it.

In order to prevent search engines indexing it , you can use simple technique , look for `robots.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

This is the principle behind "unlisted" videos on Youtube and other sites - an obscure randomly-generated string that's blocked from search via NOINDEX and NOFOLLOW.  But note that it's not secure in the true sense of the word; there's no authentication and anyone who does gain access to the URL will get through.

If you know the intended user you could restrict access by IP or IP range.  Just another thought.

Comment: Or i was thinking of giving them the option to enter a passpharse that the referring person will give.